Long Insert Times When Adding LineString Geometry to MySQL Database
I've been working with a MySQL 8.0.31-google database and initially stored points of a LineString as JSON text in a column named pointsAsJsonText. After learning about MySQL's native LineString type, I added a new column named lineString to store this data in a geometric format. To populate the new column, I updated approximately 2 million entries with the following query:
INSERT INTO table_name (id, pointsAsJsonText, lineString)
VALUES (%s, %s, ST_GeomFromText(%s))
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pointsAsJsonText = VALUES(pointsAsJsonText), lineString=VALUES(lineString)

This operation was performed in batches.
The process of updating the database with the LineString geometry took about 24 hours to complete. In contrast, prior updates that only manipulated the JSON text data took about 10 minutes. Given the similarity in data size between the JSON text and the LineString format, I did not anticipate such a significant increase in processing time. I suspect the delay may be due to internal checks or transformations that MySQL performs when handling geometric data, though when I perform similar transformations on my computer, they take only seconds.
Question: Why does inserting or updating LineString geometry significantly slow down the query performance in MySQL, and are there any configurations or optimizations that can reduce this time?

do you have a spatial index that needs updating after each insert? if so drop and rebuild the index after the updates

Apologies for not including this information in the original problem description. To check for the presence of a spatial index, I executed the following query:
SHOW INDEX FROM table_name;
The results confirm that the only index present is on the ID column. Therefore, there are no spatial indexes on this table.

So, adding the index solved the problem?

There may be some misunderstanding. Adding a spatial index wasn't applicable to my situation because, as I mentioned, my table didn't have a spatial index in the first place. The only index is on the ID column. My issue regarding the long update times persists and appears unrelated to spatial indexing, as no spatial indexes were involved. Hope this helps into clarifying the problem.
